# Lidgren peer to peer

Tags: c#, unity, networking

I am currently integrating Lidgren into my Unity game. I need to move away from the built in networking capability in Unity because of the style of game I am making, basically MMO, I will have far too much information routing through the server just to get from one peer to another.

With Lidgren I am hoping that the peers that need to send information to each other can connect and send messages while maintaining the server connection.

My question is that if I have say 2 people already connected to each other with NetPeer and a third connects to one of them, will all three automatically be connected to each other as peers, or do i have to connect the third to both other players manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NetPeer` in Lidgren is like a "node" in the network (like a [vertex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory))). You only need one per machine (or per instance of your application).

A `NetConnection` is what you use to connect `NetPeer`s together over the network (like an [edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_(graph_theory))).

Each `NetPeer` can have multiple `NetConnection`s.

You must form all of the connections between peers yourself. One peer must make make the connection and another must accept it. Creating a connection between one pair of peers does not create any other connections.

Lidgren has no built-in functionality for managing P2P *networks* (even though it can make P2P *connections*). You must write this functionality yourself.